# Why aren't my Unity rotations working properly?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation

I'm experiencing a rather annoying bug and I was hoping someone could offer some help because this just isn't making sense to me. I have a `Ballistic` script that tells the bullet to move in its local forward direction, which should be whichever way the gun is pointing. I have a `PlayerAttack` script that calls for a bullet to spawn with `OnShootEnter()`. It sets the bullets position to that of a `bulletSpawn` transform, which is a child of the gun.

`OnShootEnter()` is being properly called and `bulletSpawn` is properly assigned; and yet, when the bullet spawns, its facing `Vector3.forward`, instead of it facing `bulletSpawn.forward`. These are the only two scripts affecting the bullets spawn, rotation, and direction. Everything looks in order to me; what am I missing?

---

```
public class PlayerAttack : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    public Transform gun;
    public Transform bulletSpawn;
    public float damage;

    void OnShootEnter()
    {
        GameObject bullet
            = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.rotation);
     }
}

public class Ballistic : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject model;
    public float range;
    public float accuracy;
    public float speed;

    Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;

    void Start () 
    {
        model.transform.SetParent (this.transform);
        dir = transform.forward;
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = dir.normalized * speed;
        range -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (range <= 0)
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the sample output for debug? BulletSpawn forward != BulletForward?

Answer (score 1):

I have actually tested your scripts, and as far as I can tell, it works perfectly fine. I can rotate my gun, and shoot bullets out in the appropriate "forward direction". You can see this behaviour in the below screen capture, where I have ammended a custom editor script to provide a direct button to call `OnShootEnter()`.

[image: When I rotate the gun and shoot a bullet, the bullet exits the gun at the correct angle, and travels at the correct forward vector.]

#### Why doesn't it work for me?

There is *one* element I can not account for; `Ballistic.model`. There is no explanation for this member, and the only logic applied to it is `model.transform.SetParent(this.transform)` in the `Start()` method. We know that this member reference *has* been set up, as the entire script will not run, without it.

#### How could an additional child interfere with `transform.forward`?

I speculate that this is the source of your interference. I can only speculate, based off the name and logic, that this member represents the unique bullet model. In turn, I speculate that you have this model over the top of the game object containing `Ballistic`, and only need to ensure it is parented so it follows the movement and life cycle of your core `Ballistic` game object.

This should *not* be setting `transform.forward` to `(0, 0, 0)`; it *might* angle the game object, but not *specifically* to `Vector3.forward`. It might be possible that the rotation is being thrown off, and it only *appears* to be a deliberate `Vector3.forward` direction. This could be the result of moving two game objects that are on top of each other, which is even more likely given that the core `Ballistic` game object has a rigid body on it. It could also be the after effects of a bug, as I have personally encountered a fair few regarding the transform of an object with the addition of a new parent or child.

#### How do I fix it?

If my speculation is correct, you should simply have the model directly attached to your `Ballistic` game object, regardless. You can then interchange the mesh in order to display different models. Alternatively, simply use the core `model` game object with an attached `Ballistic` script. There is really no reason why you would need two separate game objects for the functionality of a bullet.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this in `OnShootEnter()`:

```
GameObject bullet = 
    Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.rotation);

bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * 6;
```

Comment: I gave this a shot but it didn't help... is there a reason setting the velocity here would make a difference?

Comment: Indeed, @A20T3M4, if *forward* is the wrong direction, *6 steps forward* is also the wrong direction.

Answer (score -1):

`Vector3.forward` is not really a forward , as per [official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-forward.html), it is the shorthand for `new Vector3(0,0,1)`. That means that `Vector3.forward` will increase your `z` direction by `1`, *not* by your objects *real* "forward" .

`Transform.forward` is the blue axis of the transform, in world space. In other words, the blue line is the Z axis / direction of the transform, as per [official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html). If this thing is unclear, `transform.forward` means *only* move your object along the Z axis / direction.

*Z axis / direction* is like a compass; no matter your rotation, the north and south direction will have no change; the compass will still be pointing north and south.

Comment: That's why I'm using transform.forward, not Vector3.forward. Transform.forward is shorthand for the forward position of that specific transform...

Comment: @A20T3M4 edited

Comment: I'm confused. But doesn't the transform's z-axis stay consistent with its rotation? I don't see how this prevents it from working...

Comment: @A20T3M4 , example you have a compass , no matter you rotate or not , the north and south direction will have no change , the compass still pointing at north and south .

Comment: I realise what your error was, here. Your reading off of official documentation, but not putting it into practice. The blue axis *does*, in fact, have the ability to rotate around in real space. You can see that this works in my above answer, where I demonstrate how `transform.forward` gives a variety of directions, and in most practicalities the asker's script works. Also note that I have removed *edit* from your answer, among other changes. We do not mark edits, here, as we already keep an edit record, and it gives an unwanted "forumesque" feel.